# Intellij 13 merge conflicts dialog loses gets stuck

Tags: intellij-idea, merge, intellij-13

I am having a problem with Intellij 13 when merging conflicts. When I apply my last merge change, Intellij tries to show me the "Save and finish" dialog, but apparently the merge window remains above that one (which loses its focus). At that point I cannot click on any part of Intellij and I have to kill the process.

I remember reading something about this and a change to idea.properties was the solution proposed, but I cannot find that discussion again.

Is there anyone who has a solution for this or remember the right property to add to idea.properties?

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I was actually able to find it.

On a mac you need to add this property to the idea.properties file:

ide.mac.message.dialogs.as.sheets=false

And the problem disappear.

Thanks!
Roberto

Comment: located under /Applications/IntelliJ\ IDEA\ 13.app/bin/idea.properties